# Who wins if two players have a straight?

Tags: rules

Hey i hold a weekly texas holdem at friends house and we had some confusiom twice now on couple straights. So player 1 had Q-8 and player two had Q-10 and the board came down J-10-4-K-A. Since both players hit the straight and showed Queen we went down to second card where player 2 had hit the more natural straight hand with the 10 in hand we decided he won. What would be the official ruling split pot or would player 2 have the hand?

Comment: Bad ruling. Once again, for the hundredth time, repeat after me: POKER HANDS HAVE FIVE CARDS. Exactly five, no more, no fewer. Each of these players had an Ace-high straight, and they should split the pot. Any sixth or seventh card they may have is irrelevant.

Comment: @michael it's a home game and the guy is here asking for help when something didn't make sense. There's no need to go overboard. When you don't play poker frequently some of these things aren't self-evident.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer Sorry, that was paraphrasing a quote from a cartoon. I withdraw the comment.

Comment: @Michael Oh, maybe I just don't get out much!

Comment: Okay so who wins here Table has 2 3 4 6 J
PR 1 has A 5
PR 2 has 4 5
For some reason they let player 2 win bc he also has a pair (the 4) is that correct bc player 1 had the higher straight? Or should they have just split the pot?
Thanks...

Comment: Hi Raxari. Welcome to poker. A few things. Questions you asked are not answers and belong in the comments. For the past few years we have closed what beats what types of questions as duplicates and refer people to another post which is now linked with this question. Me and some others feel that it does not require an expert answer, so we put together kind of a wiki answer about hand reading.

Answer (score 11):

I think this question is a little different than the usual question that needs the standard Best Five Cards answer. In this question, the nuance is whether player 2 gets any special consideration for having his 10 counterfeited. Does player 2 get some sort of bonus for being able to play both of his cards to make the best five-card hand, while player 1 could use only one of his cards to make the same hand?

Nope. Both players have the same hand, regardless of how they got there.

Answer (score 9):

That was the wrong way to do it.

It should have been a split pot. They both had the same best five card hand.

Answer (score 0):

Just a sidenote - in Pot Limit Omaha, where you are forced to use exactly two cards from your 4-card hole cards and three from the board, QT would have won obviously. In holdem however, one can use 0,1, or 2 of the holecards to form a 5-card combination.

I cannot remember where I read it, bu there is a holdem variant that urges to use both of your holecards. Obviously under those rules again, QT would have won.

Answer (score -1):

Player-1 have Q-8, Player-2 have Q-10 and the community cards are J-10-4-K-A
from the best 5 card rule:
P1 cards = Q-8-J-10-4-K-A = A-K-Q-J-10 =sum(A-K-Q-J-10)=60
P2 cards = Q-10-J-10-4-K-A = A-K-Q-J-10 =sum(A-K-Q-J-10)=60

both have the same cards with same sum...so both players be the winner.....

Comment: Finding the "sum" of cards, using arbitrary rules like a picture worth ten, is not relevant to poker. This is not a useful answer in any way.

Comment: yes sum is not an useful at all times but if you compare the  P1 cards = Q-8-J-10-4-K-A and  P2 cards = Q-10-J-10-4-K-A  if you arrange the cards in ranking then P1=A-K-Q-J-10-8-4 and P2 =A-K-Q-J-10-10-4 based on best 5 cards P1=A-K-Q-J-10 and P2=A-K-Q-J-10 both best 5 cards are same.....if you will take another example and I replaced P2 10 with 9's then P1=A-K-Q-J-10 and P2=A-K-Q-J-9. First we need to compare the P1 and P2 like A>=A, K>=K, Q>=Q, J>=J and 10>=9. 5th card 10>9 then the P1 be the winner. so what I am telling is we need to check the best cards on all players.

Comment: "The best cards" is not relevant in poker until the very end; it is the best **hand** that must be found. Your system requires so many exceptions that it is no longer a useful rule. It should be the last thing checked, not the first.

Comment: Take an example in community card itself have an straight with 8,9,10,J,Q with 6 players P1 =(Q, 7) P2=(K,7) P3=(K,8) P4=(A,2) P5=(3,7) and P6=(7,9) then which player be the winner.

Comment: The player with the best hand, straight to the king, not the one holding the ace as *you* are suggesting.

Comment: yes So P2 and P3 are winners